# eclipse junit system.in java

Tags: java, junit, system.in

I am trying to create a junit test on a method that calls for a user input using scanner and System.in.

The method being tested looks like this:

```
public void setUserAnswer(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    userAnswer = input.nextInt();
}
```

Currently, I am using the following set up in jUnit:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("");
        sb.append((problem.getOperand1()+problem.getOperand2()));
        String data = sb.toString();
        System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes()));
```

operand1 and operand2 are random generated numbers which the user adds and enters the answer for.

The problem I have is the System.setIn doesn't pass from the jUnit class to the class being tested.

Help?

Comment: Post a complete example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Where are you calling `System.setIn` ?  Could you please post a full example?

Comment: I am not calling System.setIn.. i guess that is my issue.  How do I pass the setIn into the original code?

Comment: By complete example, I didn't mean the input. I meant the code.

Comment: @Scholarmate why do you post code that calls System.setIn(), and then say you're not calling System.setIn(). This is more and more confusing. Post a complete code example: the class under test, and the JUnit test class.

Comment: the code is too long to post here

Comment: I am very new to java so sorry if I don't fully understand

Comment: I'm not asking you to post your whole code. I'm asking you to post a complete example reproducing the problem.

Comment: ...and why is this tagged eclipse?

Comment: I tried posting the test method and it said it was too long.

Comment: I am using eclipse to write my junit test and the testing class

Comment: I just tested using [this code](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=7RFLQabn) and things are working just fine. You need to come up with some kind of test case that we can run which has a problem somewhere. Otherwise this should be closed.

Comment: System.set in is used in the test class using jUnit.

Comment: @eis yes that works fine with scanner and setin are in the same method... however, in my case they are in two different classes.

Comment: Then create a test case showing the issue. I don't see why that would change anything.

Comment: Using the code I posted I get the following result when System.out.println(data + " " + problem.getOperand1() + " " + problem.getOperand2() + " " + problem.getUserAnswer()); is printed: 41 20 21 0.  The data being set using setin isn't being transfered to the class being tested

Comment: [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=D3SGXLfP) is the same code using disctinct classes. No problems whatsoever. Create a similar test case like I have, which we can run, that shows the problem.

Comment: Just to say it _very clear_: `System.setIn` sets the `System.in` stream for the _whole_ application.

Comment: I don't know what to say.  I have one file called MathProblem.java that contains the method I want to test.  I have another file called MathProblemTest that contains all of the jUnit methods.  When I type the code I have, it doesn't pass the setin to the file being tested.

Comment: Well, then I can tell you two things: 1. create a small and runnable example of your problem (and don't just try to post both complete classes, thanks). 2. make sure you call `setIn` _before_ the tested class creates the Scanner using `new Scanner(System.in)`.

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/d9Pq7R9h) is the jUnit Test and [link](http://pastebin.com/wzGxRLgu) is the code being tested.

Comment: that's not very much code (which is a good thing). I wonder why the system would say that's too long, because it certainly isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cut the discussion, your method could be tested in following way:

```
public class MathProblem {

  private int userAnswer;

  public void setUserAnswer(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    userAnswer = input.nextInt();
  }

  public int getUserAnswer() {
    return userAnswer;
  }
}
```

and now the Test:

```
public class MathProblemTest {

  private MathProblem mathProblem;

  @Before
  public void before() throws Exception {
    mathProblem = new MathProblem();
  }

  @Test
  public void testGetUserAnswer() throws Exception {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("41 20");
    String data = sb.toString();
    System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes()));

    mathProblem.setUserAnswer();

    assertThat(mathProblem.getUserAnswer(), equalTo(41));
  }

}
```

As the others already mention: This code behaves as expected.

So if you do not see a correct behaviour the test might be broken or the problem is in another region of your code, that you have not posted. So ask your self: Where does your example differ from this example?

Comment: Thank you.  I was missing the mathProblem.setUser.Answer().

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** be messing with `System.in` during a *unit* test.

Ask yourself what it is you're testing. Are you testing the `Scanner` code, or the code that uses whatever values are entered by the user?

Your code probably does 3 things:

- Ask user for input
- Perform operation
- Display result

In a *unit* test, you're testing the operation, not the user prompting or the display logic. Or if you do, they should be 3 different unit tests, and remember that if you're testing the user prompting, you're testing the *use* of the `Scanner`, not whether the Scanner can read `System.in`.

So, first split your code to:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Input input = promptUserForInput(new Scanner(System.in), System.out);
        Result result = performOperation(input);
        printResult(System.out, result);
    }
    // methods here
}
```

You don't have to create new classes for `Input` and `Result` if they are simple values. They could also be the same class, e.g. an instance of `MyClass`.

This way you can test if the operation works for various inputs, which is your primary concern.

```
@Test
public void testOperation1() {
    Input input = new Input(5, 15, true); // true means subtract
    Result result = MyClass.performOperation(input);
    assertEquals(-10, result.getValue());
}

@Test
public void testOperation2() {
    Input input = new Input(5, 15, false); // false means add
    Result result = MyClass.performOperation(input);
    assertEquals(20, result.getValue());
}
```

You can also test user prompting and result printing, if needed.

```
@Test
public void testPrompt() {
    String userInput = "5 15\nYes";
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
    Input input = MyClass.promptUserForInput(new Scanner(userInput), out);
    assertEquals(5, input.getNum1());
    assertEquals(15, input.getNum2());
    assertTrue(input.isSubtractRequested());
}

@Test
public void testPrint() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(buf)) {
        MyClass.printResult(out, new Result(-10));
    }
    String outText = new String(buf.toByteArray());
    assertEquals("Result is -10\r\n", outText);
}
```